# Ubuntu 16.4: Every Code Editor Close Immediatly After Opening It

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, code-editor

I'm new to Ubuntu 16.4, i use sublime as my code editor, i don't know what happened but when i open sublime it loads on left navebar and close after 4-5 seconds, i installed other code editors e.g brackets, VS Code, PHP Storm, all have same issue, but other programs are working properly like text editor, browsers etc.

Comment: You can try to run it from the terminal and see it prints any error message, you can find the location of the executable by running which sublime_text

Comment: @ErezBenHarush how do i run it with Terminal could you show me the command.....

Comment: In terminal try to run `which sublime_text` which will probably show you the path to the executable then try to run the path

Comment: This is the path `/snap/bin/subl`, hit this coimmand `which subl`...